# Correct values for SsaSpikeEstimator's pvalueHistoryLength

Tags: ml.net

In the creation of a SsaSpikeEstimator instance by the [DetectSpikeBySsa method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.detectspikebyssa?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_TimeSeriesCatalog_DetectSpikeBySsa_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_Microsoft_ML_Transforms_TimeSeries_AnomalySide_Microsoft_ML_Transforms_TimeSeries_ErrorFunction_), there is a parameter called `pvalueHistoryLength` - could anybody please help me understand, for any given time series with X points, which is the optimal value for this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

I got similar issue, when I try to read the paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.6910.pdf, I notice one paragraph

> Also, simulations and theory (Golyandina, 2010) show that it is
> better to choose window length L smaller than half of the time series length
> N. One of the recommended values is N/3.

Maybe that's why in the ML.Net Power Anomaly example, the value is chosen to be 30 for the 90 points dataset.